# Wrap tr and td around data from ajax call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how i can add a new tr and td wrapped around data received from a ajax call?  The following doesn't work.

```
$.get('/edit/'+course_id, function(data){ 

    ///add class to current tr
    $('#course_'+course_id).addClass( "info" );

    $('<tr><td>'+data+'</td></tr>').insertAfter('#course_'+course_id);

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what is comming in response data?

Answer (score 0):

You can add that to a table element. I think in IE, it needs to be attached with tbody.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data='some HTML';
    $('<tr><td>'+data+'</td></tr>').insertAfter('#course');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="course"><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

(really) difficult to answer without the HTML markup, but this might be a binding problem :

maybe you can try

```
var successCourse = function(courseId) {
    return function(data) {
        ///add class to current tr
        $('#course_' + courseId).addClass("info");
        $('<tr><td>' + data + '</td></tr>').insertAfter('#course_' + courseId);
    };
};

$.get('/edit/'+course_id).done(successCourse(course_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

The neatest way is probably...

```
$.get('/edit/' + course_id, function() {
    // do whatever else you need to do
    var formatted = $('<tr/>').append($('<td/>', { html: data }));
    formatted.insertAfter('#course_' + course_id);
});
```

This saves you from the mess of writing html tags in as strings and having to remember to close them etc, by letting jQuery do pretty much everything for you.

Here's [an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtGNw/) which shows it working. Hope this helped!